# How to show the total on the last rows with same value? (Laravel)

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I have table 'transaction_items' in my dtaabse that looks similar to this...

| id | transaction_id | qty | unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 10.00 |
| 1 | 100 | 2 | 10.00 |
| 1 | 100 | 3 | 10.00 |
| 1 | 200 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 1 | 200 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 1 | 300 | 1 | 15.00 |

Current  I fetch the data:
`$data['transaction_items'] = DB::table('transaction_items')->get();`

and run a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($transaction_items as $trans) {
 <tr>
  <td> {{ $trans->transaction_id}} </td>
  <td> {{ $trans->qty}} </td>
  <td> {{ $trans->unit_price}} </td>
  <td> * WHOLE TRANSACTION TOTAL</td>
```

This outputs the data perfectly as you would expect. Though my last value (*WHOLE TRANSACTION TOTAL) of my output is running another a query and foreach loop to get the 'total' of the whole transaction.

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php 
  $totals = DB::table('transaction_items')->select('qty', 'unit_price')->where('transaction_id', '=', $trans->transaction_id)->get();
  $ftot = 0;
  foreach ($totals as $total) {
    $ftot += $total->qty * $total->unit_price;
  }
  echo '&pound;'.number_format($ftot, 2);
  ?>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I know this is probably the wrong way of doing it, but that's why I am.

My current output looks like this...

| transaction_id | qty | unit_price | Trans Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 10.00 | 60.00 |
| 100 | 2 | 10.00 | 60.00 |
| 100 | 3 | 10.00 | 60.00 |
| 200 | 1 | 20.00 | 40.00 |
| 200 | 1 | 20.00 | 40.00 |
| 300 | 1 | 15.00 | 15.00 |

I would like it to look like this, where it shows the total after the last row with the the same transaction_id.

| transaction_id | qty | unit_price | Trans Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 10.00 |  |
| 100 | 2 | 10.00 |  |
| 100 | 3 | 10.00 | 60.00 |
| 200 | 1 | 20.00 |  |
| 200 | 1 | 20.00 | 40.00 |
| 300 | 1 | 15.00 | 15.00 |

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

**EDITED EXTRA**

I have tried using the 'reduce' method but getting...

```
$totals = DB::table('transaction_items')
    ->select('qty', 'unit_price')
    ->where('transaction_id', '=', $trans->transaction_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('transaction_id')->each(function($item) {
    $sum = $item->reduce(fn($carry, $product) => $carry + ($product['qty'] * $product['unit_price']));
    $lastRow = $item->pop();
    $lastRow['sum'] = $sum;
    $item->push($lastRow);
    return $item;
})->flatten(1);

$ftot = 0;     
foreach ($totals as $total) {
 $ftot += $total->qty * $total->unit_price;
} 
echo '&pound;'.number_format($ftot, 2);
```

But I get this error:
`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

If I do 'print_r' on my **original** $totals, this is an example of one of the rows..

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( 
 [items:protected] => Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
   [transaction_id] => 20940 
   [qty] => 4.00 
   [unit_price] => 80.0000 
  ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
   [transaction_id] => 20940 
   [qty] => 6.00 
   [unit_price] => 10.0000 
  ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
   [transaction_id] => 20940 
   [qty] => 308.00 
   [unit_price] => 0.4000 
  ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( 
   [transaction_id] => 20940 
   [qty] => 308.00 
   [unit_price] => 0.0500 
  ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( 
   [transaction_id] => 20940 
   [qty] => 1.00 
   [unit_price] => 10.3000 
  ) 
 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple - Laravel [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) is powerful

```
$total = $total->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + ($item->qty * $item->unit_price);
});
```

Or inline (I did not checked this code, probably not working)

```
$total = $total->reduce(fn ($carry, $item) => $carry + ($item->qty * $item->unit_price));
```

---

UPDATED

I did not read question properly, sorry. But collections still powerful. Btw, I think, you must think about this behaviour - more nice way is add one dimension - group by transaction and add subtotal for each group

```
$totals = DB::table('transaction_items')
    ->select('qty', 'unit_price')
    ->where('transaction_id', '=', $trans->transaction_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('transaction_id')->each(function($item) {
        $sum = $item->reduce(fn($carry, $product) => $carry + ($product['qty'] * $product['unit_price']));
        $lastRow = $item->pop();
        $lastRow['sum'] = $sum;
        $item->push($lastRow);
        return $item;
})->flatten(1);
```

Comment: tx but i'm getting an error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. in my index.blade

Comment: I put your updated part in the 'foreach ($totals as $total)' loop

Comment: @JasonF Not in foreach. Updated

Comment: Tx, but I meant to say I added to my $totals variable.

Comment: I have added in some extra information if that helps.  It seem to be throwing the error out on the reduce method